# Repeating background property (repeat-x)

Tags: css

I hope I can explain what I need to do.  See attached image for explanation.  If you look at the image you will see the 1/2 moon transparent cut out.  The image is dynamic, and scrolls different depending on the user's resolution, so I can't just make the image with the cutout in it....  What I am trying to do is the following:

solid white bar about 22px in height to left (repeat-x), then the cutout half-moon image centered, and then another solid white bar about 22px in heigh to the right (repeat-x).  I can easily get the cutout half moon in the correct position using center and margin for moving in to position... the problem is getting the solid white bar so it has the appearance as it is in the attached picture.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong and there is a better solution?

[image]

Comment: If the background is white, why don't make a white png with the transparent cutout in the center and with a huge amount of width, then add that to the bottom of the image with an extra element or a pseudo-selector like `:after`?

Comment: It's a good thought and I did think of that.  The problem is then how do I get the cutout to be centered.  If I make it a large width (e.g. 3000px, and then do a overflow:hidden) the half moon is not centered on the image, it's 1500px in since the image was 3000px.  That's the issue is that the image is width:100%.

Comment: @lobstahcrushah Perhaps the moon is not centered because you need to tell its left position to have a 50% value.  Can you associate a selector to the moon? this way you can move it around to being centered the way you want it to be? Just a thought...

Comment: I'm almost there... using this code line I'm very very close!    <div style="margin: -78px 0 0 0; z-index:1000; overflow:hidden; left:50%"><center><img src="images/halfmoon3.png" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"></center></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this CSS:

```
.test1 {
    background-image: radial-gradient(20px 10px ellipse at top, transparent 99%, white 100%);
    background-size: 100% 17px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}
```

It creates a transparent ellipse, centered, over a white background.

Comment: Thank you!  radial gradient.  Will have to file this one away.  Thank you again vals!

Comment: One question in followup- works on chrome and ff... safari however is not recognizing this...

Comment: @lobstahcrushah Here is a cross-browser solution: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+99,ffffff+100&0+99,1+100;Custom